# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') error

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, axios

It is my first time js and react.js project. and I have a problem with printing out json array data.

Here's my code

```
const [appData, setAppData] = useState({});
const [appdevData, setAppdevData] = useState('');

axios
 .all([
  .get(url1)
  .get(url2)
])

.then(
  axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
    const data1 = res1.data;
    const data2 = res2.data;

    setAppData(data1);
    setAppdevData(data2().results[0].developer.name);
  })
}, []);

return (
  <section className={styles.itemDisplaySection}>
  <div className={styles.itemDisplayFlex}>
        <table className={styles.itemDisplayTable}>
          <tr>
            <td>APP ID</td>
            <td>{appData.app_id}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>APP Type</td>
            <td>{appData.type}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>{appdevData.results[0].developer.name}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Release Date</td>
            <td>{appData.release_date}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
);
```

and here is my appData.json, and appdevData.json data.

```
appdata.json
{
    "app_id": 1089090,
    "name": "testdata",
    "header_url": "https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1089090/header_koreana.jpg?t=1658473684",
    "release_date": "2020-03-26",
    "type": "game",
    "basegame_id": null
}
```

```
appdevData.json
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "app_dev_id": 76,
            "app": "Django-server-url",
            "developer": {
                "developer_id": 65,
                "name": "SMILE"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but still there is print issue with results[] array.
here is my error code.

```
// with appdevData.results[0].developer.name
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

I've been trying to fix with map func, and props components and still have problem with it.

I know it's a simple array print out issue, but I can't find a way to fix this error.

plz help me.

Comment: _"`setAppdevData(data2().results[0].developer.name)`"_... `data2` won't be a function. Why are you trying to call it?

Comment: if im not use it there is render fail issue.
do i need to erase it?

Comment: use data2.results[0].developer.name

Comment: `<tr>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>{data2.results[0].developer.name}</td>
          </tr>`

like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting your `appdevData` change the code to (`data2` is not a function):

```
axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
    const data1 = res1.data;
    const data2 = res2.data;

    setAppData(data1);
    if (!data2.results || data2.results.length == 0) return;
    setAppdevData(data2.results[0].developer.name);
  })
```

Also, you could set your default `appData` state to null and add conditional rendering to prevent errors due to accessing properties during load.
Finally, you should display the `appdevData` state instead of `appdevData.results[0].developer.name`:

```
const [appData, setAppData] = useState(null);
const [appdevData, setAppdevData] = useState('');

...

if (!appData) return <>Loading data...</>

return (
  <section className={styles.itemDisplaySection}>
  <div className={styles.itemDisplayFlex}>
        <table className={styles.itemDisplayTable}>
          <tr>
            <td>APP ID</td>
            <td>{appData.app_id}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>APP Type</td>
            <td>{appData.type}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>{appdevData}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Release Date</td>
            <td>{appData.release_date}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
);
```